# Which doctype should I validate to to make IE7 render in standards-mode most easily?

Tags: validation, xhtml, quirks-mode

I'm working on a massive website that is supposedly "XHTML 1.0", but it is hopelessly far from being valid XHTML, let alone valid HTML.

We are forced to support IE7, and the invalid code is causing things to break in an un-fixable way in a number of places. I've researched the problem and the only way to fix it is to get IE7 to render the site in standards mode.

Since getting the site to validate is a massive undertaking already, I figure I might as well propose updating to an HTML5 doctype.

But since our primary requirement is to support IE7, and for it to render the page in IE7 standards mode, I wonder if it would be better to validate to an HTML 4.01 transitional doctype or some other doctype.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into it further, it seems that it will be easiest to validate to XHTML 1.0. I'd thought validating to HTML5 would be simpler, but it actually throws more validation errors with an HTML5 doctype than an XHTML doctype. This is because HTML5 doesn't allow a lot of the presentational HTML attributes that are in use. Oddly, HTML5 also catches things like too-few columns in a table row, while XHTML validation doesn't seem to care.

So generally, it looks like the answer is just to stick with the original doctype. Switching doctypes doesn't solve any of the invalid code and brings in additional invalidities.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of getting IE7 to work in its closest-to-standards mode these three doctypes do an exactly equivalent job:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

(Note that the first two's Transitional counterparts do a sightly different job)

In terms of making a badly invalid web site valid, the work that will be required will be different, but of a very similar quantity. However, steer clear of validating to XHTML 1.0, because IE7 cannot parse XHTML in the same way as the validator does, so your valid XHTML is really broken HTML.

There really aren't any good technical reasons why you shouldn't move to HTML5 if you want to, but at the same time it's not a magic bullet either.

Comment: Hey, the question wasn't which doctype will IE render in standards mode, but rather, which standard would be easiest to bring legacy code into compliance with. Sorry, the question was a bit confusing.

Comment: Fair enough, but note my warning on validating to XHTML. If you're not already aware of it, I recommend reading http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml

Comment: yeah, aware of the issues, and actually usually an advocate against XHTML use. we're making slow progress here. we'll get to HTML5 eventually, but validating is a good first step.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with XHTML Strict.  You can learn waaaay more about browsers rendering in modes based on doctype [here](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/).  However, you're in the clear with IE7 and any of the strict doctypes, both HTML and XHTML.